# Is there any way to react on a click on a <select> element before the menu is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, scroll

I have added a scrolling behaviour to a formular with Javascript: As soon as I click a form element, the page is scrolled to this element.

It works almost fine... by processing this JQuery on click of the formular elements:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(formularElement).offset().top - window.innerHeight/2 }, 500);
```

When I click the select element, first the menu is shown and then the page scrolls while the select menu stays where it is.

- Is there any way to process some code before the menu is shown?
- Or could I maybe prevent opening the menu, then scroll and open it by code after the page scrolling has been processed?
- Or is there a way to move the window the browser opens for the select element?

Answer (score 0):

I have included both onclick and onselect to help u distinguish; If it doesnt help u, I will remove;

```js
document.getElementById('drop_down').onchange = changed;
document.getElementById('drop_down').onclick = clicked;

function changed() {
alert('on changed')
document.getElementById('drop_down').click();
}

function clicked(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert('on clicked')
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="drop_down" >
<option value="choose">Please choose</option>
<option value="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="option 4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the scrolling should happen when an element is clicked... So doing it on change does not help.

Comment: made a minor tweak; will this help u?

Comment: I am not sure.... why it should. Try the example in here.... the preventDefault() method does not prevent the opening of the select menu so my page still scrolls away....